# Does Magento support Parenthesis symbols / Brackets in picture filename?

Tags: image, ce-1.8.1.0, importexport, nginx

0 down vote favorite

Easy step: Can anyone who uses magento try to import a picture with brackets included in the picture name? Use the default import/export tool and please let me know if you have success.

I just installed Magento 1.81 and have about 2000 products with pictures with file names formatted: Product name + (#)

For example:

3.5mm-in-car-handsfree-fm-transmitter-iphone-3g-3gs-4-4s(1).jpg

I want to upload the pictures with Magento default import/export.

I can't upload the pictures with ( ) symbols - the picture will not be visible/appear.

Other pictures display correctly. I come from Opencart where the symbols ( ) are supported on product pictures.

My settings:

Magento 1.81 
nginx/1.6.0 on VPS server
PHP 5.3.28

Answer (score 1):

I have no trouble uploading images with parentheses (they get replaced by underscores). Running Magento 1.9.0.1 with PHP 5.4.26.

If you're still stuck, it's probably easier to rename all your files. On Linux (or OSX Homebrew package `rename`) this would be:

```
rename 's/[^\w\d\.]/_/g' *
```

Run with `-n` first to see what would be renamed.